# Looking to do a Javascript Redirect by Month

Tags: javascript, arrays, redirect

I'm making an index.html page that redirects to a different page by month. It's for my investing portfolio. The idea is that each time you visit the index.html page, it will automatically redirect to the page set to the particular month. Say that I want to see which companies I invest in will announce there Ex-Dividend date this month (April), I go to index.html and it will go to the specific page for April.

I went to this site to get the random redirect code: (https://learninginhand.com/html-for-random-link)

Here is their code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "http://learninginhand.com";
urls[1] = "http://learninginhand.com/about";
urls[2] = "http://learninginhand.com/contact";
urls[4] = "http://learninginhand.com/services";
urls[5] = "http://learninginhand.com/videos";
urls[6] = "http://learninginhand.com/infographics";
urls[7] = "http://learninginhand.com/resources";
urls[8] = "http://learninginhand.com/stickaround";
urls[9] = "http://learninginhand.com/posts";
urls[10] = "http://learninginhand.com/pet";

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to JavaScript to get the month. This page helped out: (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp).

And here's the code they have on said site:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
```

Since JavaScript includes 0 in a random number code, I had to add some of my code to make it *plus one*.

```
n = n + 1;
```

Then I changed the array code:

```
var urls = new Array();
urls[1] = "01.html";
urls[2] = "02.html";
urls[3] = "03.html";
urls[4] = "04.html";
urls[5] = "05.html";
urls[6] = "06.html";
urls[7] = "07.html";
urls[8] = "08.html";
urls[9] = "09.html";
urls[10] = "10.html";
urls[11] = "11.html";
urls[12] = "12.html";
```

In the code shown in from the (https://learninginhand.com/html-for-random-link) page, this is where the redirect happens:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

I changed it to this:

```
var random = n

window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

I took away the Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length); where var random goes to, and replaced it just with *n*.